# Parsing HTML tag with ":" with lxml

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I am new in python and I'm trying to parse a Html page with lxml. I want to get text from `<p>` tag. But inside it I have a strange tag like this:

```
  <p style="margin-left:0px;padding:0 0 0 0;float:left;">
       <g:plusone size="medium">
       </g:plusone>
      </p>
```

How can I ignore this tag inside `<p>` ? I want to cut all tags with ":" inside any html page,because another functions of lxml didn't work properly with tags like this.

```
parser=etree.HTMLParser() 
tree = etree.parse('problemtags.html',parser) 
root=tree.getroot() 
text = [ b.text for b in root.iterfind(".//p")]
```

I expect to get some text inside `<p>` tags.But when i look like this, it fails on fragment like above. it writes: "b'Tag g:plusone invalid'". All i need - it is ignore all incorect tags like this. I don't know exactly how many tags like this i will have in future, but i think a problem really in ":" now, because when I use ".tag" and get name,it is just "plusone",not "g:plusone".

Comment: A simple inline CSS style attribute in a tag should not cause problems with lxml.

Comment: try maybe `&gt;` for `>` and `&lt;` for `<` and `&quot;` for `"`?

Comment: OTOH, `<g:plusone` looks like XML, not plain HTML, and I don't know how the lxml HTML parser will react to a file containing stuff like that.

Comment: @Mike what are you expecting that `text = [ b.text for b in root.iterfind(".//p")]` to return? What else is it returning? Can you please update all those information in the question?

Comment: @ PM 2Ring, What can I do with this xml in html? simple ignore or remove somehow?

Comment: Can you show the exact output of `print(text)` , and what you are expecting instead for the above html?

Comment: @ Anand S Kumar I expect text from all document. from this fragment I expect '' - nothing,because here is no text inside <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way I found to clean up the html:

```
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO

s = '''<p style="margin-left:0px;padding:0 0 0 0;float:left;">
   <g:plusone size="medium">
   </g:plusone>
  </p>'''

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(s), parser)
result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(),pretty_print=True,method="html")
print result
```

This prints

```
<html><body><p style="margin-left:0px;padding:0 0 0 0;float:left;">
       <plusone size="medium">
       </plusone>
      </p></body></html>
```

To get an etree.Element reference, namely an etree._Element, from an etree._ElementTree, just

```
root = tree.getroot()
print type(root) # prints lxml.etree._Element
```

According to [_Element-class](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html), lxml.etree._Element is the class of document instance references, in other words its what results from instantiating etree.Element, for example

```
el = etree.Element("an_etree.Element_reference")
print type(el) # prints lxml.etree._Element
```

Comment: It's not a good idea,because result - is a string after all and I need "etree.Element". if i will use  "from_string" - it will slow down my programm. i can use for this "beautiful soup",but lxml is faster. Thx for advice!

Comment: @Mike: tree.getroot() an an etree.Element reference, namely an etree._Element and that's a really odd class name switcheroo compared to Java. Hard to reasearch too.

Answer (score 0):

The `g:` is a namespace prefix. The actual tag name is only `plusone`. So, lxml is correct in only returning `plusone` as the tag name. See a summary of namespaces [here](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp).

As I understand it, lxml's HTML Parser is not namespace aware. However, the XML Parser is. Presumably, given that this HTML document contains XML, it is most likely actually an XHTML document (if not, then it is probably an invalid HTML document and you cannot expect lxml to parse it correctly). Therefore, you need to run it through the XML Parser rather than HTML Parser. lxml's namespace API is explained in their [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces).

However, with the fragment you provided the parser returns this:

```
>>> d = etree.fromstring('''<p style="margin-left:0px;padding:0 0 0 0;float:left;">
...        <g:plusone size="medium">
...        </g:plusone>
...       </p>''')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3032, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:68121)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1786, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:102470)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1674, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:101299)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1074, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:96481)
  File "parser.pxi", line 582, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:91290)
  File "parser.pxi", line 683, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:92476)
  File "parser.pxi", line 622, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:91772)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix g on plusone is not defined, line 2, column 23
```

Note that it complains that the "`Namespace prefix g on plusone is not defined`." Presumably, elsewhere in your document the namespace prefix is defined. As I don't know what that is, I'll just make something up and define if on the `plusone` tag in your fragment:

```
>>> d = etree.fromstring('''<p style="margin-left:0px;padding:0 0 0 0;float:left;">
...        <g:plusone xmlns:g="something" size="medium">
...        </g:plusone>
...       </p>''')
>>> d
<Element p at 0x2563cd8>
>>> d.tag
'p'
>>> d[0]
<Element {something}plusone at 0x2563940>
>>> d[0].tag
'{something}plusone'
```

Notice that the `g:` prefix was replaced with the actual namespace (`{something}` in this case as I set is like so: `xmlns:g="something"`). Usually the namespace would actually be a URI. So you may find that your tag looks something like this: `{http://where.it/is/from.xml}plusone`

Nevertheless, I find working with namespaces rather bothersome when they are not necessary. You may actually find it easier to use the HTML parser which ignores the namespaces. Now that you know that the tag is named `plusone`, not `g:plusone` you may be able get on with your work using just the HTML parser.